# Splitting an array at random in Scala

Tags: scala, random, collect

I'm building a decision tree system in Scala, but some of the entries in my data have identical attributes. 
I've gotten around this by implementing a "random" node type, allowing the query to randomly select which branch to traverse, but I'm getting a "MatchError" when trying to split the remaining examples at random. 
My current code:

```
def splitRandom(examples: Array[String]): Array[String]={
        examples.collect {case x if(r.nextInt(100) < 50) => x}
}
```

"examples" is an array of strings, with each string being a line containing a single data entry with all of its attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`collect` isn't a good choice for random behavior because the same condition can be evaluated twice (first on an `isDefinedAt`, and then a second time to compute the value); if it says true the first time and false the second--on the same input--match will be upset.  Use `filter` instead:

```
examples.filter(_ => r.nextInt(100) < 50)
```

Comment: Had to remove the `if` but other than that very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Amadeus9 - Oops.  Fixed now.  I assume you might pick values other than 50, which is why you're using `nextInt`?

Comment: Yeah. For now I'm having it pick without bias, but I may end up changing that.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution fits your issue:

```
import util.Random
val shuffled = Random.shuffle(your_array)
val (first, second) = shuffled.splitAt(your_position)
```

I found this trick when I wanted a rdd.randomSplit's counterpart for Scala List or Array

You can do some type transformation if needed